# Variable requerida en Rest

Tags: c#, json, rest

quiero hacer una peticion with [post] y si algun campo is null no quiero seguir al servicio. Quiero parar el flujo en el controlador, El problema surje en el modelstate.isvalid returna true cuando deberia retornar false.

este es el codigo:

Model:

```
public class IdentityBrokerSettingsDetails
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Tenant { get; set; }

        // With interrogation mark you make it nullable
        [Required]
        public bool? Account { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool? StatusUserLogin { get; set; }

        public IdentityBrokerSettingsDetails(string tenant, bool? account, bool? statusUserLogin)
        {
            Tenant = tenant;
            Account = account;
            StatusUserLogin = statusUserLogin;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PostIdentitySettingsDetails([FromBody] IdentityBrokerSettingsDetails identityBrokerSettingsDetails)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) //doesn't work
                return BadRequest();

        }
```

Comment: Me parece que el problema es que si es required, pero aceptas null, entonces siempre va a ser true...

Comment: Los booleanos no deberías ponerlos nulos

Comment: Intentaste definiendo un constructor sin parametro en la clase IdentityBrokerSettingsDetails?

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el action he inspeccionas el parametro que llega en el post, puedes ver que esas propiedades requeridas estan en null ?